# Magento redirect for language

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, store-view, language

I have this problem:

1. www.prova.com
2. www.prova.com/it/
3. www.prova.com/eng/

i want my guest entry directy into website 2)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a general redirect question. You will be better off by [asking this on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: The question is on-topic because is a problematic of multishop Magento.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to your .htaccess

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /it/
```

Basically it redirect the root and only the root URL to the /it URL.

If you would like to redirect all then that would be different.

[Source of that](https://serverfault.com/questions/9992/how-to-get-apache2-to-redirect-to-a-subdirectory)

Comment: I thought there was the direcly solution in Magento backend .

Comment: Did it work for you ?

Comment: A question ...if i change The url secure(and unsecure i think) for all single Store (Skin,media,ecc...)? Now i have 2 home: www.prova.Com and www.prova.com/It. It's same page but in 2 url